# Install FastReport 5 trial

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have installed Delphi 10 Seattle Trial (Architect).
I try to install FR Professional 5 Trial (from official site).

I use recompile.exe from FR, then I start the Delphi, and FR components are not shown in tool palette, frxClass is not found.

I have installed all packages from FR/LibD23, I added TfrxReport component on design GUI. After click on this component FastReport is open, but when I try to compiling project, frxClass is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall all instances of FR, remove all FR's files and folders (see system and hidden files too) and then run FR 5 Trial installer with "Run as administrator" option

Comment: Ok, I done this. When I start Delphi with Administrator privileges, then the FastReport is shown in ToolBar. Then I set up user privileges for FastReport and Delphi folder, then run recompile.exe without Admin privileges. After this I run Delphi as user and installed all dcl*.bpl packages.